# Cannot assign data for parameter string from tempdata asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, tempdata

I had my code from controller here.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> myFunction(string myCode)
    {

        myCode = myCode == null ? TempData["thisIsTheCode"].ToString() : myCode;
        return View();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> redirectToMyFunction(string thisIsTheCode)
    {
        TempData["thisIsTheCode"] = thisIsTheCode;
        return RedirectToAction("myFunction");
    }
```

i am passing data from redirectToMyFunction using tempdata. i want to update my parameter string from myFunction, but why i can get the TempData[] value but can't assign it to my parameter myCode?
i am confusing here.
Anyone have this issue?

Comment: Check value of `myCode` that is received in `myFunction` action. Is it null?

Comment: yes. it is null, all the time. i had assigned the the tempdata value to myCode, but seems like didn't assigned into myCode. i am frustrated.

Comment: What is the value in `TempData["thisIsTheCode"]` in `myFunction`? Also what is the value for `thisIsTheCode` in `redirectToMyFunction`?

Comment: i had tried like this
public async Task<IActionResult> redirectToMyFunction(string thisIsTheCode)
    {
        TempData["thisIsTheCode"] = "ABC";
        return RedirectToAction("myFunction");
    } 
then i inspect the tampdata from myFuntion, it does has "ABC", but when i assign it to myCode. it appears null.

Comment: But thats not possible. If tempdata has "ABC" and `myCode` is null then how could that Line of code not work? Not possible.

Comment: same thought here. that is why i am asking around regarding this.

Comment: You will get no answer sam because this line of code has to work: `myCode = myCode == null ? TempData["thisIsTheCode"].ToString() : myCode;` You are probably doing something else that your code does not show. Are you aware that `TempData` only works for the next request and not qny requests afterwards?

Comment: i think is not the tempdata fault, even i hard code it to be like myCode = myCode == null ? "hardcoded": myCode;
remain not working

Comment: So just assign it to another variable then like `string other = myCode == null ? "Hardcoded" : myCode;` and use `other` variable.